# How high does a F35B Fighter (whilst hovering) have to be to see the earth rotating at 1000/mph?

Tags: rotorcraft

Is there a way, or an aircraft that can actually perform this? The F35B fighter jet has hovering capabilities. The only "supposed" images of this 1000 mph spin is from NASA, **but the clouds do not move**, so it is, in most logic; a computer-animated clip.

Comment: I'm guessing that it is the helicopter part that ain't working.

Comment: If it is hovering, it does not see the earth rotate, it would defy the definition of hovering.

Comment: I was under the impression that it could hover in the air (like in the sky), and not just a couple feet above the ground.

Comment: You Aviator guys guys run a hard market :P lol

Comment: The definition of hovering is not height-dependent.

Comment: Then if the jet is "holding a fixed position" (with help from the north star(?)), a what point/altitude will you see/notice a spin of 1000 mph?

Comment: A spin/rotational motion is measured in angle unit per time unit (e.g. degree per second), not in length unit per time unit. See [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/torque-angular-momentum/torque-tutorial/v/relationship-between-angular-velocity-and-speed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better answered by Space.SE, since it's about orbital mechanics.

Comment: @SteveV. this is not even orbital mechanics: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3426/1467

Comment: @Federico - Of course there would be an XKCD for this exact situation.  :]

Comment: It seems to me (as a layman, I am neither pilot nor physicist) that if a plane is 'hovering', that no matter the altitude, it will be moving at the same 'speed' as the planet, and hence not see any of Earth's rotation. (By same speed, I mean both 'earth through the cosmos' and 'earth's rotational speed')

Comment: It also seems to me (although this one might get me flagged as rude) that the OP is starting to show a habit of asking 'interesting' questions which have problems of factuality (i.e. military over antarctica, planes hovering in space)

Comment: You should take this question to Physics SE for a full explanation (which will expand on why it is impossible to define fixed point and stationary and why, in order to see the rotation of the Earth, you must also be moving) and to Sceptics SE for the "supposed rotation" (I don't even know what you're saying here - do you doubt that the Earth rotates?).

Comment: I would like to migrate this to Physics SE, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

At an absolute fixed position you would see the earth move at 1 inch altitude.  But you would need to traveling 1000 mph relative to the surface of the earth to hold a fixed position relative to the North star.

At lower altitude the atmosphere moves with the earth.  Otherwise we would experience 1000 mph wind on the surface.

There is a spirited debate on fixed position. And this is physics. To me the intent from the OP was clear - take rotation out of the equation.

- At the equator hold a position such that you can draw a straight line
  between you the rotational axis of the the earth and the center of
  the Sun.  To achieve that you would need to travel apx 1000 mph
  relative to the surface of the earth and should be able to see that
  at any altitude.
- Or directly above the axis (north or south) point directly at the Sun. How high would you need to be see the earth spin below you?  I don't think you would see it spin as it relatively low angular velocity (one rotation every 24 hours).

I agree this is not an aviation question. I did not think it would into this level of physics. I am good with it getting migrated. If an moderator wants to delete my answer I am good with that.

Comment: [physicist] an "absolute fixed position" does not exist [/physicist]

Comment: @Federico And that is why I added  hold a fixed position relative to the North star.

Comment: The motion of a point on the equator relative to the North Star is [unlikely](http://astrosociety.org/edu/publications/tnl/71/howfast.html) to be 1000 mph.

Comment: @mins unlikely? that's (almost) exactly the equatorial speed around the axis.

Comment: @Federico: While it is known the linear speed at the equator is about 1000 mph (relative to the center), the Earth is not fixed relative to Polaris, hence the linear speed of a point on the equator relative to Polaris is unlikely to be the same. For a start the Earth moves around the Sun (66,000 mph relative to the Sun). Also I doubt we know what is our velocity relative to Polaris, as we barely know the distance of Polaris, [in the range of 400 l.y.](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/01/20/north-star-distance-earth_n_2513621.html) Or am I wrong?

Comment: @mins The intent of hold a fixed position is clear enough.

Comment: @Blam  The intent of a "fixed position" is only ever clear when the reference frame is also specified.  If you say "fixed position above the Earths surface", then you are only fixed in respect of that point of the Earth.  To everyone else, you are not in a fixed position.  It is just not possible to say a fixed position is clear.  The North Star is also moving, moving really fast, so if you are fixed relative to the North Star, then you are also moving really fast relative to an observer in a different reference frame.

Comment: @Simon The fact you say the North Start is not a fixed position means you get the intent.  Come on.  You name the reference - you know the intent.

Comment: @Blam: I understand what you mean in the answer, in your effort to clarify things to the OP: the Earth rotates 15° per hour around the pole axis, hence at the equator, with a radius of 6,400 km this translates to a linear speed of 1,000 mph (albeit your answer doesn't mention the equator, at the pole it doesn't work). But talking about being fixed relative to something creates the confusion contrary to what you expected. What you may take as the "fixed" viewing point is, for instance, any point on the line between Earth and Sun.

Comment: @Blam Sorry, I don't know the intent at all. Your statement that you would see the earth move at 1 inch if you move at 1000 mph (or whatever the speed at the given latitude, to stay fixed relative to the North Star is nonsense. We don't know how fast the North Star is moving relative to the Earth but it is many orders of magnitude greater, in the order of many 10s of thousands of miles per hour. The North Star only appears to be fixed over small periods of observation. It moves vast distances every day and, in not too long a time, will not even be a useful north (losely) fixed point.

Comment: @mins North Star was introduced by the OP to clearly mean not hover with the rotation.  The net is clear.  As soon you hover NOT with the rotation you would see the rotation.

Comment: OK, this has nothing to do with aviation.  Please take it to physics SE.

Comment: @Blam: Yes, the answer must first explain him that we don't know what is the effect of being motionless relative to Polaris, in the Ecliptic frame. And as Simon says, this  cannot be explained on Aviation without exiting the on-topic scope.

Comment: @Simon Then to you my answer is nonsense.  North Star fixed  fixed position was introduced by the OP.  It clearly means a frame of reference removing the rotation of the earth.   The question is closed and I don't think this interaction adds value.

Comment: @Simon You migrate questions not answers.  The question is already closed.